Is it possible to use images from Azure Compute Gallery in Azure Container Registry and vice versa?
I want to know the difference between Azure Compute Gallery and Azure Container Registry.
Both of them works as a registry to store images.
Azure Container Registry is more similar to docker registry – it can be used as an alternative to it and I am able to use images from that resource with pods in my AKS instance.
Azure Compute Gallery has a similar concept – it also stores images. However, I haven't seen any tutorial that would show how to use images from it in pods in AKS. That made me think that the core concept of these two solutions are different.
Unfortunately, I was not able to find a proper description with differences between these two resources.
Could you please help me better understand the core concept of these two and tell me whether is it possible to use images from Azure Compute Gallery in AKS? I would like to also know whether is it possible to create a docker image from Azure Compute Gallery and push it to Azure Container Registry (or docker registry).

In short, Azure Compute Gallery is for VMs and Azure Container Registry for Docker images.
You cannot store Docker images in Azure Compute Gallery nor it makes sense to use it with AKS.
